# Trying to install python module 'num2words' but getting following issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, python-module

In my 64 bit **windows** machine, I'd installed **pip 20.0.2** successfully. Then I tried to install **numwords** using the following command but got errors.

```sh
pip install num2words
```

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
```

[image: ERROR]

I'm sorry as the above screen shot not much clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the output to your question **as text**. Besides some other problems it is barely readable as a screenshot in dark-red in black.

Comment: You're running pip for the global environment, which apparently sits in `Program Files` on your system - you don't have access there as a non-admin user, so you get a permission error. You can run the command window as administrator to get around it, but you probably should reconsider how Python is installed and if you should be using the global environment from there.

Comment: Got the solution just adding --user switch with the command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+OSError+13+permission+denied

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install num2words
```

You get the error is because it's trying to user older version of python.

Comment: Got the solution just adding --user switch with the command.

pip install num2words --user

Comment: In my case working this commands .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution just adding **--user** switch with the command.

```
pip install num2words --user
```